# SML - Passing NONE or SOME as argument

Tags: smlnj

I have just started on SML and I am having trouble trying to pass NONE/SOME as parameters to a function.

```
fun fx (SOME x) (SOME y) f = f x y
    | fx (SOME x) (NONE) f = NONE
    | fx (NONE) (SOME y) f = NONE
    | fx (NONE) (NONE) f = NONE;

fun add x y = x + y;

fx (SOME 2) (SOME 4) add;
```

What I am trying to do is to add two numbers only if neither values are NONE. But I get the following error:

```
Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int -> int -> 'Z option
  operand:         int -> int -> int
  in expression:
    ((fx (SOME 2)) (SOME 4)) add
```

If remove the cases for NONE, i.e:

```
fun fx (SOME x) (SOME y) f = f x y
```

Then it works alright. I don't know where exactly am I making a mistake. f parameter is not optional, yet it is treating as one.

Comment: How about redefining `fun add x y = SOME (x + y);`?

Comment: add is just an example, fx is supposed to be generic for any function requiring two operands (add, multiply etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You've already answered the "how", so I will try and explain the "why".

Look at the type of `fx` in the REPL:

```
val fx = fn : 'a option -> 'b option -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c option) -> 'c option
```

It produces a `'c option` (it is known from your `NONE` cases that the result is an `option` type).
(Note that `'a -> 'b -> 'c option` is `'a -> ('b -> ('c option))`, not `('a -> 'b -> 'c) option`.)

Since your first case is `f x y`, that must produce an `option` type - and `add` doesn't.

This is what the error message is trying to say; since `SOME 2` and `SOME 4` are `int option`s, `fx (SOME 2) (SOME 4)` has the type `(int -> int -> int option) -> int option` (the "operator domain" is `int -> int -> int option`), but `add` is an `int -> int -> int`.
(The use of the word "operator" here is a bit confusing. You get used to it.)

If you want the more generic type `'a option -> 'b option -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c option`, you need to wrap the result (as you've found):

```
fun fx (SOME x) (SOME y) f = SOME (f x y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Nalin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11697936/nalin-ranjan) pointed out in the comments, I had to redefine the method, just not on `add` but on `fx` actually.

```
fun fx (SOME x) (SOME y) f = SOME (f x y)
```

Comment: Correct, by including options that return NONE the compiler expects all returned types to be either SOME or NONE. That is why returning an integer or NONE failed. SMLNJ is a strongly typed language!